# combine row from csv with python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv, for-loop

For example the below dataframe I have this

```
jan,feb,mar
AAA,BBB,CCC
Dog,Cat,Ant
111,222,333
Mon,Tue,Wed
1990,1991,1991
XXX,YYY,ZZZ
```

I would like to append  row 1 and row 2 to first row and so on

```
jan,feb,mar,AAA,BBB,CCC,Dog,Cat,Ant
AAA,BBB,CCC,Dog,Cat,Ant,111,222,333
Dog,Cat,Ant,111,222,333,Mon,Tue,Wed
111,222,333,Mon,Tue,Wed,1990,1991,1991
Mon,Tue,Wed,1990,1991,1991,XXX,YYY,ZZZ
1990,1991,1991
XXX,YYY,ZZZ
```

and if I have a thousand of row how do I get the answer

thank you for your answer

Comment: Ok so group 3 rows?

Comment: You need to post some progress.  This question appears to be asking people to write the program for you.  Obviously you're going to need to know how to read files one line at a time while looping.  It's likely you'll need to construct a new list of strings as you are looping.  Give it a shot, and update the question with your initial attempt, and it is far more likely that you will get some help.

Answer (score 1):

Use `pd.concat` with `axis=1`  and `DataFrame.shift()`.

```
n = 3
df = pd.concat((df.shift(-i) for i in range(n)), 1)
```

Full example:

```
import pandas as pd

data = '''\
jan,feb,mar
AAA,BBB,CCC
Dog,Cat,Ant
111,222,333
Mon,Tue,Wed
1990,1991,1991
XXX,YYY,ZZZ'''

fileobj = pd.compat.StringIO(data) # replace this with 'path/to/file'
df = pd.read_csv(fileobj, sep=',', header=None)

n = 3
df = pd.concat((df.shift(-i) for i in range(n)), 1)

# And some formatting...
df.columns = range(len(df.columns))
df.fillna('', inplace=True)

print(df)
# df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False, header=None) # output if you want.
```

Returns:

```
      0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8
0   jan   feb   mar   AAA   BBB   CCC   Dog   Cat   Ant
1   AAA   BBB   CCC   Dog   Cat   Ant   111   222   333
2   Dog   Cat   Ant   111   222   333   Mon   Tue   Wed
3   111   222   333   Mon   Tue   Wed  1990  1991  1991
4   Mon   Tue   Wed  1990  1991  1991   XXX   YYY   ZZZ
5  1990  1991  1991   XXX   YYY   ZZZ                  
6   XXX   YYY   ZZZ
```

Comment: Oh I got it. Thank you very much.